# Regex: PHP to C# | Help needed with converting

Tags: c#, php, regex

Problem explained below.

**PHP**

```
public function DoSomething($content) {
    preg_match('/\s*\$\s*(.*)/is', $content, $matches);
    if(Count($matches) == 0)
        return $content;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

**C#**

```
public static string DoSomething(string Content) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content)) 
        return null;

    string pattern = "pattern needed";

    if (Regex.Match(Content, pattern).Groups.Count > 1)
        return Content;
    else
        return null;
}
```

My problem is the regular expression **"/\s*\$\s*(.*)/is"**. It is not valid in C#.

How do I write this in .NET? Do you know a an easier way to get the same php result in C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: It is explained below. Read line 1. Quote: "My problem is the regular expression "/\s*\$\s*(.*)/is". How do I write this in .NET? Do you know a an easier way to get the same php result in C#?"

Comment: what problems did you run into specifically besides "give me the code"?

Comment: The proper regex pattern. It's not valid in C#.

Comment: For ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @devnull, you don't know what kind of work I am doing and yet you are trying to say obvious things. I am translating a coworkers project from PHP to C#, that means: pattern was already there, I had to deal with the existent thing.

But thanks anyways!

Comment: @user3319473 - Be nice.  For someone who is asking for help from people (for free), you aren't being very kind to those who are *trying* to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to set the `pattern` you'll need to preface it with the `@` sign to properly escape the backslashes. Secondly, the `/{pattern}/{flags}` pattern doesn't work in .NET; you need to pull out the pattern and send the analogous flags as `RegexOptions`:

```
string pattern = @"\s*\$\s*(.*)";

if (Regex.IsMatch(Content, pattern,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline))
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw., Regex.Match does not work as a boolean. new Regex(...).IsMatch(Content); was my solution now.

Comment: @user3319473, thanks a lot; I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the modified code:

```
public static string DoSomething(string Content) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content)) 
        return null;

    string pattern = @"\s*\$\s*(.*)";

    if (Regex.Match(Content, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups.Count > 1)
        return Content;
    else
        return null;
}
```

I have removed the forward slashes from around the pattern, and converted the flags to enum values, `IgnoreCase` and `SingleLine` (Dotall).

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\A\s*\$\s*(.*)\z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don't match at line breaks; Parentheses capture

Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “$” literally «\$»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*)»
   Match any single character «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»

\$1

Insert the backslash character «\»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
```

Answer (score 0):

I have few comments on your conversion:

```
public static string DoSomething(string Content) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content)) 
        return null;

    string pattern = "pattern needed";

    if (Regex.Match(Content, pattern).Groups.Count > 1)
        return Content;
    else
        return null;
}
```

1. At first point if you just have to check there is a match, you should use `Regex.IsMatch`.
2. To represents literal string we prefix string with `@`, which helps to escape the slashes etc.
3. To specify Regex option you can specify like `(?is)` as shorthand representation instead of using function's second parameter.

So the final code should look like:

```
public static string DoSomething(string Content)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content))
        return null;

    string pattern = @"(?is)\s*\$\s*(.*)";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(Content, pattern))
        return Content;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: "IsMatch" missing in your code. And I've already realized the part with using IsMatch instead of Match. Thank you!